# Remove index from Array 1 and insert it into Array 2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, insert, uibutton

How can I remove an index from Array 1 and insert it into Array 2? Array 1 and Array 2 are [UIButton].

For example: How to be if

```
@IBOutlet var Array1: [UIButton]!
@IBAction func ArrayToRemove(sender: UIButton!) {
                    sender.hidden = true 
                    }
```

Comment: Given an `index`, you want to remove the value at that `index` from `array1` and insert it inside `array2`?

Comment: Yes. I mean remove an object at a specific index in array 1 and insert it to Array 2.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
var list0 = [
    UIButton(type: UIButtonType.ContactAdd),
    UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom),
    UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
]

var list1 = [
    UIButton(type: UIButtonType.InfoDark),
    UIButton(type: UIButtonType.InfoLight)
]

let index = 1

let elm = list0.removeAtIndex(index)
list1.insert(elm, atIndex: index)
```

### Result

```
list0 // [1, 5, 7]
list1 // [2, 3, 4, 6]
```

Comment: How to be if                                                                                            '@IBOutlet var Array1: [UIButton]!                                                       @IBAction func ArrayToRemove(sender: UIButton!) {
                sender.hidden = true 
                }'

Comment: I think you should explain us what you **really** need to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the index (in the array) of the object you want to move/remove, but you DO know its value then use this approach:

```
    let a = UIBarButtonItem(); let b = UIBarButtonItem(); let c = UIBarButtonItem()
    var array1 = [a,b,c]

    //look for the index of c in array1
    let indexOfButton = array1.indexOf(c)

    //assign the object at that index to a property so you can add it to array2
    let buttonToMove = array1[indexOfButton!]
    var array2 = [buttonToMove]

    //if you need to remove the object from the first array and place it in the second you can use the removeAtIndex method
     let buttonToMove = array1.removeAtIndex(indexOfButton!)
     var array2 = [buttonToMove]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `removeAtIndex` function, for example:

```
let removedButton = buttonsArray.removeAtIndex(index)
```

Comment: I understand how to remove from Array if Array[Int]. I can't do it with Array[UIButton].

Comment: It's exactly the same: `let removedButton = buttonsArray.removeAtIndex(index)`

Comment: @KevinGuan, I **did** answer the question. I told the OP to use `removeAtIndex`, and even edited my question to provide a code example.

Comment: @DuncanC: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​Okay, with that code example which makes sense. I didn't downvote and have removed my comment by the way. I also edited to remove these *comment stuff* - something like those shouldn't in an answer but a comment IMO.

Comment: My answer is conditional on making sure I understand the question. If that is not what the OP is asking then the answer may not solve the OPs problem, so the first part of the answer should remain. Not a great fit for the format, I agree, but sometimes we have to use the tools at hand in creative ways.

Comment: @DuncanC: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​That's what my point: We better ask OP that *Do I understand your question correctly?* in comments, then post an answer. If you're not sure, don't post an answer. And seems that you sure *your answer will answer the question*, hence I removed comment/edited.